# Allow Client to connect to Database via Web Page

Tags: asp.net, web

Is it possible to allow a client connect to a database (E.g. with Excel) via a WebPage?  The WebPage acts like a proxy and handles the user connection to the DB?  The user can then query the DB with their client app.

I have never heard of a way of achieving this, but a colleague mentioned it was possible in ASP.NET.

Comment: you can query a db directly with excel, why via a webpage?

Comment: @Gwny Sure - but this would add authentication\authorization too

Comment: why is this bad? do you want everyone to gain access to the db?